# Missing bcache0 backing device

Tags: fedora, cache, bcache

In my new Fedora 31 install there is no `\dev\bcache0`. The caching device is Raid 1:

```
# ls -d /dev/b*
/dev/block  /dev/bsg  /dev/btrfs-control  /dev/bus

# bcache-super-show /dev/md127
sb.magic                ok
sb.first_sector         8 [match]
sb.csum                 CDCAF0DD6B68FD24 [match]
sb.version              1 [backing device]

dev.label               (empty)
dev.uuid                b17ceaac-27ec-44d8-8bbb-235cfaa0c4a4
dev.sectors_per_block   1
dev.sectors_per_bucket  1024
dev.data.first_sector   16
dev.data.cache_mode     1 [writeback]
dev.data.cache_state    1 [clean]

cset.uuid               de075a7c-af4e-43e9-b229-804322e3d263

# lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   700M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                          8:2    0   700M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda3                                          8:3    0    26G  0 part
│ └─luks-9793c78f-723c-4218-865f-83dbc4659192 253:1    0    26G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─sda4                                          8:4    0   162G  0 part
  └─luks-569b1153-2fab-4984-b1b6-c4a02ee206ef 253:0    0   162G  0 crypt /
sdb                                             8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1                                          8:17   0    40G  0 part
└─sdb2                                          8:18   0  71.8G  0 part
sdc                                             8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdc1                                          8:33   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md127                                       9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid1
sdd                                             8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdd1                                          8:49   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md127                                       9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid1
sde                                             8:64   1  58.9G  0 disk
├─sde1                                          8:65   1    20G  0 part
└─sde2                                          8:66   1  38.9G  0 part
sr0                                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

# blkid | grep -E "md127|sdb1"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="057a2f23-c7b1-4264-a534-183ef9cad53b" TYPE="bcache" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="505789f1-0523-4c62-bdb1-81bc0cc7bff1"
/dev/md127: UUID="b17ceaac-27ec-44d8-8bbb-235cfaa0c4a4" TYPE="bcache"
```

Does the above output mean that the device is Ok and not corrupted?

Right after this new install I had it working as before in the previous Fedora 30 install. Then I resized the caching device partition (`sdb1`) and now I can't make the backing device to appear as a bcache device.

I can't register it:

```
# echo /dev/md127 > /sys/fs/bcache/register
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

# echo de075a7c-af4e-43e9-b229-804322e3d263 > /sys/fs/bcache/register
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Neither attach

```
# echo de075a7c-af4e-43e9-b229-804322e3d263 > /sys/block/md127/bcache/attach
-bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

That file exits:

```
# ll /sys/block/md127/bcache/attach
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Jan  5 10:37 /sys/block/md127/bcache/attach
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/block/md127/bcache/stop; echo 1 > /sys/block/md127/bcache/detach; sleep 2; echo /dev/md127 > /sys/fs/bcache/register

# echo 32dbab45-f8b3-4ef8-89e2-32007fc4970b > /sys/block/md127/bcache/attach

# ll /dev/bcache0
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 252, 0 Jan  5 12:56 /dev/bcache0
```